# Verizon Emails are Coming Out Blank?

Tags: email, html-email, carrier

I send tens of thousands of emails out, and all my Verizon subscribers are getting blank emails.

Looking into the HTML/HAML they return to me, it seems that Verizon's email parser is placing all the content after my `clear:both` div tags inside of the Div tag.

Here's an example of my clear div tag and its other attributes.

```
%div{:style => "clear:both;display:block;overflow:hidden;visibility:hidden;width:0;height:0; font-size: 0; float: left;"}
```

How can I work around this problem, so that my emails are displayed the same way for Verizon subscribers as for everyone else?

Comment: Yo that vote-down is lame. This information is valuable to the entire web dev community.

Answer (score 1):

Simple!

Just add some Foobar text inside of the clear div. For some reason, this bypasses their bug with div tags set to clear consuming all the div tags below it.

An example :

```
%div{:style => "clear:both;display:block;overflow:hidden;visibility:hidden;width:0;height:0; font-size: 0; float: left;"}
  Whatever Text.
```

In plain HTML:

```
<div style="clear:both;display:block;overflow:hidden;visibility:hidden;width:0;height:0; font-size: 0; float: left;" class="clear">
  Whatever text.
</div>
```